# Content type errors - "The Byline text" error

Tags: views

I'm having trouble creating a content type. I can't seem to figure out to fix these validation errors. I'm not user what they mean.

```
The Byline text - Full content view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - Teaser view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - RSS view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - Search index view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - Search result highlighting input view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - Colorbox view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - Revision comparison view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
The Byline text - Tokens view mode is using the following invalid tokens: [node:author], [node:created].
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Event though I had unchecked 'Display author and date information.' under 'Display settings', I still needed to empty the text fields or at least remove the tokens from them.

Comment: So what is the actual answer then to this question? Just reading your answer here makes me doubt, can you clarify a bit please (by editing your answer)?